# How do I use a Java method inside the JSP page and pass an EL value as an argument?

Tags: jsp, el, scriptlet

I have just a question about passing parameters to the java method inside JSP.

I have a java class called `ParameterCrypto` and it contains `decode(String str)` and `encode(String str)` static methods.

I would like to pass an EL value into the method parameter like:

```
<%=ParameterCrypto.decode("${searchbean.searchvalue}")%>
```

But the issue is when passing `"${searchbean.searchvalue}"` into the decode method it gets as String, not the value it holds.

Is there a solution?

Comment: EL is translated to Java so instead of using EL you should directly go for the Java equivalent - or convert the entire expression to EL.